# OpenId Connect and Custom Identity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid-connect, okta

I'm using the Okta example for implementing OpenIdConnect in an Asp.NET 4.6.x MVC web application.  The application uses Unity for Dependency Injection and one of the dependencies is a custom set of classes for the Identity Framework.  I'm not using the Okta API because the IdP is not actually Okta and I'm assuming there's proprietary stuff in it.  So it's all .NET standard libraries for the OpenId portions.

I can walk through the code after clicking login and it will carry me to the IdP and I can log in with my account, and then it will bring me back and I can see all of the information from them for my login.  But it doesn't log me in or anything as it does in the example from Okta's GitHub.

Basically I'm wondering if the identity customization is what's interfering with the login and if there's a way to get in the middle of that and specify what I need it to do?

```
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
            ClientId = clientId 
            , ClientSecret = clientSecret
            , Authority = authority
            , RedirectUri = redirectUri
            , AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive
            , ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken
            , Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile
            , PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            , TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { NameClaimType = "name" }
            , Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                {
                    //var tokenClient = new TokenClient($"{authority}/oauth2/v1/token", clientId, clientSecret);
                    var tokenClient = new TokenClient($"{authority}/connect/token", clientId, clientSecret);
                    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, redirectUri);

                    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
                    }

                    //var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient($"{authority}/oauth2/v1/userinfo");
                    var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient($"{authority}/connect/userinfo");
                    var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
                    var claims = new List<System.Security.Claims.Claim>();
                    claims.AddRange(userInfoResponse.Claims);
                    claims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("id_token", tokenResponse.IdentityToken));
                    claims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken));

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenResponse.RefreshToken))
                    {
                        claims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken));
                    }

                    n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaims(claims);

                    return;
                }
                , RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                  {
                    // If signing out, add the id_token_hint
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                    {
                          var idTokenClaim = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                          if (idTokenClaim != null)
                          {
                              n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenClaim.Value;
                          }

                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                  }
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token(s) returned by Okta have to be managed by your application in order to perform the login action. The OIDC token returned will need to be verified and validated by you, and then a decision made as to whether to accept the OIDC token. If so, you take action to log the user into your application. Recieving an OIDC token as a result of an OpenID Connect flow doesn't by itself log you into an app. The app needs to do some more work based on the token content before taking a login or reject action.

Comment: It turns out this is really more or less what I had to do. The code above does handle a good deal of it but the part that just worked automatically in the sample application has been subjugated by the customizations in my case.  So I ended up writing some code to handle the bits in the 'AuthorizationCodeReceived' section of my code sample above.